# Tibco BW -Enable logs

Tags: tibco, businessworks

How can I enable logs on the TIBCO Admin? I want to check whatever file I have posted to the listener. The listener is able to receive the request.

Answer (score 3):

You can set

```
Trace.Startup=true
Trace.Task.*=true
Trace.JC.*=true
Trace.Engine=true
Trace.Debug.*=true
```

in the deployed tra file and then restart the application and run it. 
Then check detailed log file located in the <install-path>\tibco\tra\domain\application\logs folder.

Please keep in mind that all manual settings will be cleared after redeploy. To keep it permanent, set it in the bwengine.tra file in <install-path>\tibco\bw\<version>\bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable the debug logs for TIBCO classic Admin then you need to do following steps:
 Set " -tsm_traceLevel" param to -1 in the hawkagent.cfg file under \tra\domain\.
 Set logdebug=true in the 2 *.properties files in under \tra\domain\
 delete/backup the files from log folder under \tra\domain\
 Restart admin and hawkagent for domain